# Octave xlswrite seems to work but I can't find the file

Tags: linux, excel, octave

I am trying to use xlswrite in Octave to write to an excel file. The xlswrite command seems to work fine but I don't find the excel file in the current working directory after xlswrite is executed. In fact, I can't find it anywhere on my machine.

For example, I tried the following code to write data to a file:

> > A = eye(5,5);
> >     status = xlswrite('myA.xlsx',A)
> >         Detected XLS interfaces: status =  1

The write operation seems to have been successful but I can't find myA.xlsx anywhere. Any help in resolving this issue will be much appreciated.

FYI, I am using Octave 4.0.0 and io 2.2.9. The OS is linux mint 17.2.

Thanks,
HC

PS: The problem seems to occur when the working directory is on the cloud (Google Drive in the present context). If I change the working directory to a local directory, xlswrite seems to work fine.

Comment: I seem to have posted this in the wrong group. My apologies.

Comment: run `pwd()` (stands for print working directory). Whatever is displayed it's where you will find your file.

Comment: Thanks. Did that. But the file is not there. Note that xlsread works fine. It reads an excel file from the current working directory. It's xlswrite that doesn't seem to work. After some playing around, I think the problem may be to do with writing to a directory on the cloud. When I set the working directory to a local directory, the xlswrite function works fine.

Comment: ah! That's an important detail you should have mentioned from the start. I suggest you edit your question with all details, including details of your "cloud".

Comment: Thanks @carandraug. I have updated the question.

Comment: @hpc: So this doesn't look like a problem in xlswrite. Can you temporarly disable the google drive daemon and try again? Perhaps it's blocking something?

Comment: Thanks @Andy. I use InSync for syncing. I killed the InSync process and tried to write to the local directory where Google Drive files are placed. Still doesn't work.  What is interesting is that I can read from a file stored on the Google Drive but not write to a file.

Comment: I would step through xlswrite and see what could cause the problem. I can't help further since I don't use cloud services